# How do I convert 4 bytes of a ByteString to an Int?

Tags: haskell

How can I convert a ByteString to an Int?

I have the following 4 bytes that I want to convert (it represents the size in bytes of a .bmp file):

`"v\SOH\NUL\NUL"`

which I know equals 374

Comment: Did you try treating the 4 bytes in the size field as a 4 byte number? Also, how big is the file?

Comment: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183391(v=vs.85).aspx) is a good explanation about how `BMP`-file is structured.

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FourCC) is what @DavidYoung mentioned. And [here](http://www.fourcc.org/rgb.php) is a full list of FourCC bytes.

Comment: Nevermind, readInt doesn't do what I thought it did. And the file is 374 bytes.

Comment: @David How do you treat a Bytestring as an Int? That's the whole point of this post. I tried using Binary's decode, but it throws a "not enough bytes" error. It seems to use 5 bytes to encode an Int instead of 4. And I don't understand how FourCC is relevant, unless it says how to decode an Int.

Comment: You can't just add all the bytes together directly. You need to bit shift them so they're in the right place (note that the byte order for .bmp is little endian so the least significant byte is first): ```ord 'v' + (ord '\SOH' `shiftL` 8) == 374```

Comment: @David Perfect, thank you. I'm going to have to look up what shifting does though, I've never done anything that low before. Do you know any good guides that cover the topic? (If they're easy to find, I'll just Google it on my break)

Comment: @David Why did you only shiftL (ord 'v')? How do you know what needed to be shifted, or is it always the second byte?

Comment: Lets look at a two byte number first. Remember this is a little endian format so the least significant byte (the one with the one's place) is read first (so it's on the left). If we look at `0000 0001, 1100 1001`, if read those as two bytes and add them we end up with the number `1100 1010`. We want to end up with the original number. If we shift the second one to the left by 8 bits we end up with `0000 0000 1100 1001`. When we add this to the other number we get `0000 0001 1100 1001` (in LE). So you have to shift everything, but you're shifting the first one by 0*8 so it doesn't do anything.

Comment: The aligns each byte so actually ends up in the right byte of the integer. When you shift the second byte that you read from the file by 8 bits for example, you "put it" into the second byte of the integer that you're storing it in.

Comment: @David So it's like how you multiply a number by a power of 10 to adjust for the the place (in a decimal system)?

Comment: @David You sir, are a patient God. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For binary parsing, have a look at the `binary` package - http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary

It defines a `Get` monad, so you can write something like:

```
data Header { ftype :: ByteString, size_ :: Word32, reserved_ :: ByteString, offset_ :: Word32 } 
parseHeader = do
  ft <- getByteString 2
  size <- getWord32le
  reserved <- getByteString 4
  offset <- getWord32le
  return $ Header ft size reserved offset
```

and later:

```
main = do
  bytes <- hGetContents handle
  let header = runGet parseHeader bytes
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a small functions working that demonstrates the idea

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B

lEBsToInt :: B.ByteString -> Int -- littleEndianByteStringToInt
lEBsToInt bs = let bsI = B.take 4 bs in -- 1.
    fst $ B.foldl (\(s,i) b -> let shiftBy = i * 8 in -- 2.
        (s + (ord b `shiftL` shiftBy), i + 1)) (0,0) bsI --3.
```

1. Get the first 4 bytes of a ByteString
2. Calculate the amount to shift by
3. Fold over the ByteString, summing the result of shifting the current byte by the current offset

`lEBsToInt "v\SOH\NUL\NUL" = 374`

This could definitely be improved, but I was happy with it